# How to update value in p:dialog and display in the p:dialog

Tags: primefaces, dialog

I have a datatable, and at the last column I will have an edit action, it will trigger the dialog box. However, I found the value in the dialog box is not updated. Can anybody to help on this?

My code as below. In fact the bean.currentItem.name and bean.currentItem.age should base on my selection from the table. I check the bean.currentItem is not null and is refer to my selection from preEdit method, but the value never show up in p:dialog.

```
<p:dataTable ....>
    <p:column...
    <p:column...
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputLabel value="Update" />
        </f:facet>
            <p:remoteCommand name="preEdit" action="#{bean.preEdit}"
                process="@this" update="@this @form:dlg">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.currentItem}"
                            value="#{thisItem}" />
            </p:remoteCommand>
            <p:commandLink styleClass="no-decor"
                oncomplete="preEdit();PF('dlg').show();" value="Edit"/>                         
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>

<p:dialog header="#{lbl.tt_cat_upd}" widgetVar="dlg" id="dlg"
            resizable="false" >
    <h:outputLabel value="#{bean.currentItem.name}" />
    <h:outputLabel value="#{bean.currentItem.age}" />
</p:dialog>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about removing your `p:remoteCommand` and let your `p:commandLink` do all the work for you?

Assuming you have a `h:form` surrounding both your `dataTable` and your `dialog`

```
        <p:commandLink action="#{bean.preEdit}" process="@this" update="dlg" styleClass="no-decor" oncomplete="PF('dlg').show()" value="Edit">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.currentItem}"
                        value="#{thisItem}" />
       </p:commandLink>
```

If your `dataTable` is not in the same form with your `dialog`, you might replace `update="dlg"` by `update=":formIdContainingDialog:dlg"`

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for your help. It solve my problem, but it trigger another issue to me. I added another column call delete, and the delete command link will trigger p:confirmDialog box. When I click Yes from the p:confirmDialog box, the system throws NullPointerException from the xhtml page, p:dialog field.

Comment: What about adding `rendered="#{bean.currentItem != null} "` to your dialog?